# Создание ярлыка на рабочем столе при подключении флешки. Windows 10

Tags: windows

Можно ли как-то средствами Windows 10, без использования стороннего ПО, сделать так, чтобы при подключении флешки/внешнего диска и подобных накопителей, на рабочем столе появлялся ярлык для этого накопителя. А его отключении ярлык должен отключаться. Эта фишка есть в Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое очевидное написать два скрипта на PowerShell. Один будет создавать ярлыки подключенных устройств при подключении, второй будет их удалять при отключении.